# How to select a row of a spark dataframe based on values in a list?

Tags: sql, list, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list l looking like this `l = ["3", "on", "red"]` and a spark dataframe df looking like this:

```
cel1 cel2 cel3 cel4 cel5 cel6 rule1 rule2 rule3
2    3    20   5    67   2    1     off   green
12   3    21   3    60   21   3     on    red
32   6    23   2    67   1    9     on    green
```

How can I select the rows of the spark dataframe where the values of the last 3 columns match the values of the list l. For example, in this case only the second row should be returned.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the list to generate a list of conditions, and reduce them to one condition using a bitwise AND. Make sure that the column type matches that in the list `l` - e.g. column `rule1` should be of string type, not int type.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce

l = ["3", "on", "red"]
cols = ["rule1", "rule2", "rule3"]

df2 = df.filter(
    reduce(
        lambda a, b: a & b,
        [F.col(x) == y for (x, y) in zip(cols, l)]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using spark-sql and concat_ws() function.

```
df = spark.sql(""" with t1 (
 select  2 c1,  3   c2,  20 c3, 5  c4, 67 c5,   2  c6, 1  c7,  'off' c8, 'green' c9 union all
 select  12 c1,  3   c2,  21 c3, 3  c4, 60 c5,   21  c6, 3  c7,  'on' c8, 'red' c9 union all
 select  32 c1,  6   c2,  23 c3, 2  c4, 67 c5,   1  c6, 9  c7,  'on' c8, 'green' c9 
 )  select   c1  cel1,   c2  cel2,   c3  cel3,   c4  cel4,   c5  cel5,   c6  cel6,   c7  rule1,   c8  rule2,   c9 rule3    from t1
 """)
df.show()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
|cel1|cel2|cel3|cel4|cel5|cel6|rule1|rule2|rule3|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
|   2|   3|  20|   5|  67|   2|    1|  off|green|
|  12|   3|  21|   3|  60|  21|    3|   on|  red|
|  32|   6|  23|   2|  67|   1|    9|   on|green|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+


inp = ["3", "on", "red"]
cols = ["rule1", "rule2", "rule3"]
inp_str=",".join(inp)
cols_str=",".join(cols)

spark.sql(f"""select * from df where concat_ws(",",{cols_str})='{inp_str}' """).show()

+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
|cel1|cel2|cel3|cel4|cel5|cel6|rule1|rule2|rule3|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
|  12|   3|  21|   3|  60|  21|    3|   on|  red|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
```